# Using next() and res.send .Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client. Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]:

Tags: node.js, express

I am new to node js and express and learning the basicsss,, In other code errors i saw, i used to debug by seeing the throws part but itsnt here..

EDIT: I am new to the concept of  middleware & next()and that has created the error as seen in upvoted answer.

Code :

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.use('/add-product',(req,res,next)=>{
    console.log("This is add-product page")
    res.send("<form action='/product' method ='POST'><input type='text' name ='title'><button type ='submit'>Submit</button></form> ")
    next()
})
app.use('/product',(req,res,next)=>{
    console.log('this is product-page')
    res.redirect('/')
})
app.use('/', (req,res,next)=>{
    res.send('Welcome to NodeJS')
})
app.listen(3000)
```

Error :

```
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
This is add-product page
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:387:5)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:603:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\A\Desktop\vs code\the complete tutorial\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:794:10)
    at ServerResponse.contentType (C:\Users\A\Desktop\vs code\the complete tutorial\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:624:15)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\A\Desktop\vs code\the complete tutorial\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:149:14)
    at C:\Users\A\Desktop\vs code\the complete tutorial\app.js:14:9
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\A\Desktop\vs code\the complete tutorial\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\Users\A\Desktop\vs code\the complete tutorial\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:328:13)
    at C:\Users\A\Desktop\vs code\the complete tutorial\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:286:9
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\A\Desktop\vs code\the complete tutorial\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Can't set headers after they are sent to the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-to-the-client)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are finished with processing your request and fetching the data for it and what to send the final response, use `return` before the res.send

The above error you are facing is because of the `next()` function you are calling in the `'/add-product'`. It will check for the next function to be called.

`next()` function is used when after calling a function you want another function to run for the same route.

Try this:

```
app.use('/add-product', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log("This is add-product page")
  return res.send("<form action='/product' method ='POST'><input type='text' name ='title'><button type ='submit'>Submit</button></form>");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
app.use('/add-product',(req,res,next)=>{
    console.log("This is add-product page")
    res.send("<form action='/product' method ='POST'><input type='text' name ='title'><button type ='submit'>Submit</button></form> ")
    next()
})
```

After you `res.send(...)` you can't next here. Use `next()` func when you want to create a middleware with condition.

Answer (score 0):

You should always use return while sending response to client.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.use('/add-product',(req,res,next)=>{
    console.log("This is add-product page")
    return res.send("<form action='/product' method ='POST'><input type='text' name ='title'><button type ='submit'>Submit</button></form> ")
    
})
app.use('/product',(req,res,next)=>{
    console.log('this is product-page')
    return res.redirect('/')
})
app.use('/', (req,res,next)=>{
    return res.send('Welcome to NodeJS')
})
app.listen(3000)
```